# value of list in model is updated but it does not reflect on composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating demo project for using jetpack compose with mvvm , i have created model class that holds the list of users.. those users are displayed in list and there is a button at top which adds new user to the list when clicked...
when user clicks on the button an the lambda updates activity about it and activity calls viewmodel which adds data to list and updates back to activity using livedata, now after the model receives the new data it does not update composable function about it and hence ui of list is not updated..
here is the code

```
@Model
data class UsersState(var users: ArrayList<UserModel> = ArrayList())
```

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val usersState: UsersState = UsersState()
    private val usersListViewModel: UsersListViewModel = UsersListViewModel()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        usersListViewModel.getUsers().observe(this, Observer {
            usersState.users.addAll(it)
        })
        usersListViewModel.addUsers()
        setContent {
            UsersListUi.addList(
                usersState,
                onAddClick = { usersListViewModel.addNewUser() },
                onRemoveClick = { usersListViewModel.removeFirstUser() })
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel

```
class UsersListViewModel {

    private val usersList: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<UserModel>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<UserModel>>()
    }
    private val users: ArrayList<UserModel> = ArrayList()
    fun addUsers() {
        users.add(UserModel("jon", "doe", "android developer"))
        users.add(UserModel("john", "doe", "flutter developer"))
        users.add(UserModel("jonn", "dove", "ios developer"))
        usersList.value = users
    }

    fun getUsers(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<UserModel>> {
        return usersList
    }

    fun addNewUser() {
        users.add(UserModel("jony", "dove", "ruby developer"))
        usersList.value = users
    }

    fun removeFirstUser() {
        if (!users.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            users.removeAt(0)
            usersList.value = users
        }
    }
}
```

composable function

```
@Composable
    fun addList(state: UsersState, onAddClick: () -> Unit, onRemoveClick: () -> Unit) {
        MaterialTheme {
            FlexColumn {
                inflexible {
                    // Item height will be equal content height
                    TopAppBar( // App Bar with title
                        title = { Text("Users") }
                    )
                    FlexRow() {
                        expanded(flex = 1f) {
                            Button(
                                text = "add",
                                onClick = { onAddClick.invoke() },
                                style = OutlinedButtonStyle()
                            )

                        }
                        expanded(flex = 1f) {
                            Button(
                                text = "sub",
                                onClick = { onRemoveClick.invoke() },
                                style = OutlinedButtonStyle()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    VerticalScroller {
                        Column {
                            state.users.forEach {
                                Column {
                                    Row {
                                        Text(text = it.userName)
                                        WidthSpacer(width = 2.dp)
                                        Text(text = it.userSurName)
                                    }
                                    Text(text = it.userJob)

                                }
                                Divider(color = Color.Black, height = 1.dp)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

the whole source code is available [here](https://github.com/kushal2011/jetpack_compose_with_mvvm/tree/data_and_events_flow)

I am not sure if i am doing something wrong or is it because jetpack compose is still in developers preview , so would appreciate any help..
thank you

Answer (score 12):

Ahoy!

Sean from Android Devrel here. The main reason this isn't updating is the ArrayList in `UserState.users` is not observable – it's just a regular `ArrayList` so mutating it won't update compose.

### Model makes all properties of *the model class* observable

It seems like this might work because `UserState` is annotated `@Model`, which makes things automatically observable by Compose. However, the observability only applies one level deep. Here's an example that would never trigger recomposition:

```
class ModelState(var username: String, var email: String)

@Model
class MyImmutableModel(val state: ModelState())
```

Since the `state` variable is immutable (`val`), Compose will never trigger recompositions when you change the `email` or `username`. This is because `@Model` only applies to the properties of the class annotated. In this example `state` is observable in Compose, but `username` and `email` are just regular strings.

### Fix Option #0: You don't *need* @Model

In this case you already have a `LiveData` from `getUsers()` – you can observe that in compose. We haven't shipped a Compose observation yet in the dev releases, but it's possible to write one using effects until we ship a observation method. Just remember to remove the observer in `onDispose {}`.

This is also true if you're using any other observable type, like `Flow`, `Flowable`, etc. You can pass them directly into `@Composable` functions and observe them with effects without introducing an intermediate `@Model` class.

### Fix Option #1: Using immutable types in @Model

A lot of developers prefer immutable data types for UI state (patterns like MVI encourage this). You can update your example to use immutable lists, then in order to change the list you'll have to assign to the `users` property which will be observable by Compose.

```
@Model
class UsersState(var users: List<UserModel> = listOf())
```

Then when you want to update it you have to assign the `users` variable:

```
val usersState = UsersState()

// ...
fun addUsers(newUsers: List<UserModel>) {
    usersState.users = usersState.users + newUsers 
    // performance note: note this allocates a new list every time on the main thread
    // which may be OK if this is rarely called and lists are small
    // it's too expensive for large lists or if this is called often
}
```

This will always trigger recomposition any time a new `List<UserModel` is assigned to `users`, and since there's no way to edit the list after it's been assigned the UI will always show the current state.

In this case, since the data structure is a `List` that you're concatenating the performance of immutable types may not be acceptable. However, if you're holding an immutable `data class` this option is a good one so I included it for completeness.

### Fix Option #2: Using ModelList

Compose has a special *observable* list type for exactly this use case. You can use instead of an `ArrayList` and any changes to the list will be observable by compose.

```
@Model
class UsersState(val users: ModelList<UserModel> = ModelList())
```

If you use `ModelList` the rest of the code you've written in the Activity will work correctly and `Compose` will be able to observe changes to `users` directly.

### Related: Nesting @Model classes

It's worth noting that you can nest `@Model` classes, which is how the `ModelList` version works. Going back to the example at the beginning, if you annotate both classes as @Model, then all of the properties will be observable in Compose.

```
@Model
class ModelState(var username: String, var email: String)

@Model
class MyModel(var state: ModelState())
```

*Note: This version adds `@Model` to `ModelState`, and also allows reassignment of state in `MyModel`*

Since `@Model` makes all of the properties of the class that is annotated observable by compose, `state`, `username`, and `email` will all be observable.

## TL;DR which option to choose

Avoiding `@Model` (Option #0) completely in this code will avoid introducing a duplicate model layer just for Compose. Since you're already holding state in a `ViewModel` and exposing it via `LiveData` you can just pass the `LiveData` directly to compose and observe it there. This would be my first choice.

If you *do* want to use `@Model` to represent a mutable list, then use `ModelList` from Option #2.

---

You'll probably want to change the ViewModel to hold a MutableLiveData reference as well. Currently the list held by the ViewModel is not observable. For an introduction to `ViewModel` and `LiveData` from Android Architecture components check out the [Android Basics course](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not observed so changes won't be reflected.
[In this article](https://edit.theappbusiness.com/jetpack-compose-a-point-in-time-8c9459f6c58c) under the section 'Putting it all together' the List is added.

```
val list = +memo{ calculation: () -> T}
```

Example for your list:

```
@Composable
fun test(supplier: UserState) {
   val list = +memo{supplier.users}
   ListConsumer(list){
       /* Do other stuff for your usecase */
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to change the values of your UserModel you might need to add the @Model annotation to this dataclass

Comment: my usersState class containing list of userModels is already annotated with @model , and after your suggestion i tried using the above code with +memo but still having the same issue